# C++ error two or more data types in declaration of function

Tags: c++

In a piece of code I am passing two parameters both of same type `b2Vec2 *`

```
void bool isVelocityAllowToCar(b2Vec2 *newVelocity, b2Vec2 *preVelocity);
```

When I build my project it showing me following error.

```
two or more data types in declaration of 'isVelocityAllowToCar'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The problem is the return type you specify. `void bool` is not valid, it's two types `void` and `bool`. You just need to remove the `void` and it should work:

```
bool isVelocityAllowToCar(b2Vec2 *newVelocity,b2Vec2 *preVelocity);
```